# Angular2 error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: angular

I used angular in version 2.2.3 and always it worked good.
When i upgraded to version 2.4.4 one error has ocurred (The error in picture below).

After hours searching what was happening i found that problem is because not is more possible use functions `() => ExampleModule` in attribute loadChildren of Router.

For use this i needed changed `loadchildren: () => ExampleModule` to `loadchildren: 'path/example.module#ExampleModule'`, and angular worked as expected.

> Now i want know if the function type () => is not more supported to
>   use or this happened because i created a error ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carlinhos,

Looks like this was introduced today:

Changelog:
router: enable loadChildren with function in aot

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#244-2017-01-19

Looks like this has to do with lazy loading vs eager loading to fix AOT compilation, as the compiler was not available at the right time to resolve the route issue.

I'm thinking the issue might have to do with the function's return rather than the function itself -- it's expecting a factory to be returned now, so it's possible the function is no longer valid.

So, functions are still allowed, but I think they have to return a factory.  It looks like strings were always allowed, and they work because they do not utilize a provided factory:

https://github.com/DzmitryShylovich/angular/blob/47b1031ba4552fd840817da9b7aa7da5780854a8/modules/%40angular/router/src/config.ts#L321

I think if you aren't using AOT/ lazy vs eager loading, you probably won't care about this and can use the string.

Comment: Thank you for help. I know that string mode and functions already used times ago, but i throwed this question because in angular site have no more explanations about function mode, only string mode.
Now im not using AOT, but for everything to work as expected, i will continue writing with string mode.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#asynchronous-routing